# how handlebar templates are rendered by the browser

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to know the low-level implementation of ember framework. When the handlebar templates defined inside script tag with type="text/x-handlebars-template" getting appended to the DOM? Also, how browser excludes that script?(i.e How actual flow of rendering a page is modified. I am new to ember and handlebars and just curious to know this.

Comment: [Research before you ask](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run a couple of experiments with an older version of Ember for understanding more, what is really happening under the hood. (It is totally relevant to the latest Ember versions also.) You can read my findings in the Readme here: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/ember-resolver-experiment

Answering for your question, Ember will run the following function during the initialization process: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-htmlbars/lib/system/bootstrap.js#L40

As you see, there is a `bootstrap` function, which uses jQuery to find those special templates scripts in your DOM. It will compile with the `ember-template-compiler` and it will be added to the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object. (You can check in your console if you type `Ember.TEMPLATES`.)

As you see in this `bootstrap` function, these template script tags will be removed (line 72) from the DOM after compilation.

Each version of Ember package comes with different ember.js files (for production, and for debugging) and you can find there ember-template-compiler.js, which is basically the handlebar compiler. You don't need handlebar.js at all in ember project, because this ember-template-compiler.js is your handlebar.js.

If you would like to learn more about Ember.js, I wrote a free tutorial which start from the very basics: [Ember.js tutorial](http://yoember.com)

Answer (score 0):

For the last question first :

A script is never seen in a browser so there is no need to exclude it from beeing rendered. WebComponent templates are now a replacement for such script template but if you are using some older template they will still be displayed so a script tag is a better solution for now if you want a template to be compatible with all browsers. So the rendering of the page is not affected. At the end of the page load you'll run your handlebar script that will calculate the template rendering and once it's done will insert it in the dom (typically replace a placeholder).

For your first question :

The question is unclear do you want to know how the template is appended to the dom or when it is appended or how it is rendered ? The best way to know that is to look at the source of handlebars.js. I don't know for ember.js but if you're just using handlebar you'll have to add the result of your processing manually in the dom (by using jquery for instance).

Comment: Thanks @christophe Thiry. My first question is that when templates are compiled and the resultant elements are appended to DOM in an ember application? Whether in document load event or some other thing?

Comment: I can't tell about ember I don't use it, I can just tell about Handlebars.js standalone sorry. I'll give a try to ember one day but not soon.